# CAS: Content encryption header (enc) not set

Tags: cas, jce

I got this exception when I tried to log in. As you can see i successfully got the ticket granting ticket. However, for somereason I get the "CAS is Unavailable" screen. Down in the stack trace I can see `org.jose4j.lang.InvalidAlgorithmException: Content encryption header (enc) not set.` Which might be the root problem, but I can't really find a good solution for that.

```
   2016-09-16 10:21:13,868 INFO [org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
    =============================================================
    WHO: audit:unknown
    WHAT: TGT-**********************************************glwdSALMyP-cas01.example.org
    ACTION: TICKET_GRANTING_TICKET_CREATED
    APPLICATION: CAS
    WHEN: Fri Sep 16 10:21:13 CEST 2016
    CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
    SERVER IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
    =============================================================


2016-09-16 10:21:13,868 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.web.support.WebUtils] - Evaluating request to determine if warning cookie should be generated
2016-09-16 10:21:13,868 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.web.WarningCookieRetrievingCookieGenerator] - Removed cookie with name [CASPRIVACY]
2016-09-16 10:21:13,868 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.web.support.DefaultCasCookieValueManager] - Encoding cookie value [TGT-**********************************************glwdSALMyP-cas01.example.org@0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1@Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0]
2016-09-16 10:21:13,884 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.util.DefaultCipherExecutor] - Encrypting via [null]
2016-09-16 10:21:14,055 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.web.FlowExecutionExceptionResolver] - Ignoring the received exception due to a type mismatch
org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException: Exception thrown executing org.jasig.cas.web.flow.SendTicketGrantingTicketAction@53e9a90f in state 'sendTicketGrantingTicket' of flow 'login' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]'
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:77)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:101)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:228)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:395)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:116)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:547)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:390)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:105)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:228)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:395)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:116)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:547)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:390)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:231)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:195)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:537)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:259)
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:228)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jasig.cas.security.ResponseHeadersEnforcementFilter.doFilter(ResponseHeadersEnforcementFilter.java:227)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jasig.cas.security.RequestParameterPolicyEnforcementFilter.doFilter(RequestParameterPolicyEnforcementFilter.java:250)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jasig.inspektr.common.web.ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.doFilter(ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.java:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:279)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Ensure that you have installed JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files. Content encryption header (enc) not set.
    at org.jasig.cas.util.DefaultCipherExecutor.encryptValue(DefaultCipherExecutor.java:135)
    at org.jasig.cas.util.DefaultCipherExecutor.encode_aroundBody0(DefaultCipherExecutor.java:86)
    at org.jasig.cas.util.DefaultCipherExecutor$AjcClosure1.run(DefaultCipherExecutor.java:1)
    at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:149)
    at org.jasig.inspektr.aspect.TraceLogAspect.traceMethod(TraceLogAspect.java:44)
    at org.jasig.cas.util.DefaultCipherExecutor.encode(DefaultCipherExecutor.java:85)
    at org.jasig.cas.util.DefaultCipherExecutor.encode(DefaultCipherExecutor.java:1)
    at org.jasig.cas.web.support.DefaultCasCookieValueManager.buildCookieValue_aroundBody0(DefaultCasCookieValueManager.java:72)
    at org.jasig.cas.web.support.DefaultCasCookieValueManager$AjcClosure1.run(DefaultCasCookieValueManager.java:1)
    at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:149)
    at org.jasig.inspektr.aspect.TraceLogAspect.traceMethod(TraceLogAspect.java:44)
    at org.jasig.cas.web.support.DefaultCasCookieValueManager.buildCookieValue(DefaultCasCookieValueManager.java:53)
    at org.jasig.cas.web.support.CookieRetrievingCookieGenerator.addCookie_aroundBody0(CookieRetrievingCookieGenerator.java:67)
    at org.jasig.cas.web.support.CookieRetrievingCookieGenerator$AjcClosure1.run(CookieRetrievingCookieGenerator.java:1)
    at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:149)
    at org.jasig.inspektr.aspect.TraceLogAspect.traceMethod(TraceLogAspect.java:44)
    at org.jasig.cas.web.support.CookieRetrievingCookieGenerator.addCookie(CookieRetrievingCookieGenerator.java:66)
    at org.jasig.cas.web.flow.SendTicketGrantingTicketAction.doExecute(SendTicketGrantingTicketAction.java:85)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: org.jose4j.lang.InvalidAlgorithmException: Content encryption header (enc) not set.
    at org.jose4j.jwe.JsonWebEncryption.getContentEncryptionAlgorithm(JsonWebEncryption.java:131)
    at org.jose4j.jwe.JsonWebEncryption.getCompactSerialization(JsonWebEncryption.java:242)
    at org.jasig.cas.util.DefaultCipherExecutor.encryptValue(DefaultCipherExecutor.java:133)
    ... 93 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you have to add keys in the `cas.properties` for the TGC encryption:

```
# The encryption secret key. By default, must be a octet string of size 256.
tgc.encryption.key=***

# The signing secret key. By default, must be a octet string of size 512.
tgc.signing.key=***
```

In order to get keys use [this](https://github.com/mitreid-connect/json-web-key-generator) tool.

[Here](https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/installation/Configuring-SSO-Session-Cookie.html) is the reference in the CAS 4.2.x documentation.

It mentioned that the CAS server will automatically generate keys for the TGC if not set before, but I couldn't find them in my console so I used the mentioned tool. Don't forget to choose `oct` as the key type.